# How to change routes when auth status changes in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

What I need to do is to render the react native routes based on the users auth status. Right now I am doing this the wrong way, by having an interval running to check for auth status change:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { checkAuth } from './auth';
import { LoggedInRoutes, LoggedOutRoutes } from './router';

export default () => {
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState(false);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      checkAuth()
        .then((res) => { setLoggedIn(res); setReady(true); console.log('checked..') })
        .catch((err) => alert(err));
    }, 1500);
  }, [loggedIn]);

  if (!isReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        onFinish={() => setReady(true)}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    loggedIn ? <LoggedInRoutes /> : <LoggedOutRoutes />
  );
}
```

But obviously that is quite bad. I am using async storage to save the user when he authenticates and remove him from storage when he clicks the logout button.

Is there a way to check for changes in async storage and re-render the routes? or run a function that changes loggedIn state when user click login/logout button?

Comment: The component is re rendered every time the loggedIn state changes. But since you are using your custom authentication system, I am not sure of how to figure this out! Maybe you can setup a listener, can you provide the auth code?

Comment: I have found the solution. I passed a function as a parameter in my route components and I call it when the user gets authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use switchNavigator in react navigation

reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/auth-flow – mr-nobody 40 secs ago    Edit   Delete

Answer (score 0):

this approach will works like a charm.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import OnBoardingRoutes from './onBoarding.routes';
import AppRoutes from './app.routes';
import checkFirstUsage from "./checkFirstUsage/path";


const Routes: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [firstUsage,setFirstUsage] =useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     async function check() {
          const fU = await checkFirstUsage()
          setFirstUsage(fU)
          setLoading(false)
     }

     check()
  },[])

  if (loading) return null  // or any better component

  return firstUsage ? <OnBoardingRoutes /> : <AppRoutes />;
};

export default Routes;
```